# Java reflection does not work as expected

Tags: java, reflection

I just wrote this code to test something for a better understanding of reflection.

This is the ReflectionTestMain class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ReflectionTestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ReflectionTest rt = new ReflectionTest();
            Class<ReflectionTest> c = ReflectionTest.class;
            Field f = c.getDeclaredField("value");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(rt, "text");
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getValue");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            String value = (String) m.invoke(rt);
            System.out.println(value);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the ReflectionTest class.

```
public class ReflectionTest {
    private final String value = "test";

    private String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This code prints test but I expected it prints text. What is the reason that this does not work and how can I fix that?

Comment: I don't know much about reflection however, could it be the reason that your `value` is declared as `final`

Comment: But I thought it works anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the variable is properly updated, it isn't propagated to the `getValue()` method.

The reason for this is that the compiler optimizes the program for you.

Since the compiler knows that the variable `value` is not changed, it compiles it to inline access directly to the string pool, instead of going through the variable. This can be sees by running `java -p` on the class file

This can be solved by using a initizer block or constructor for the string constant, or making the statement more complex to "fool" the compiler.

```
class ReflectionTest {


    // Use either
    private final String value;
    {
        value = "test";
    }
    // Or 
    private final String value;
    public ReflectionTest () {
        value = "test";
    }
    // Or
    private final String value = Function.identity().apply("test");
    // Or

    //   Do not replace with + as the compiler is too smart
    private final String value = "test".concat(""); 
    // Depending on your required performance/codestyling analyses

    private String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of `"test".concat("")` you can simply use `"test".toString()`. This isn’t even about smartness, as the Java Language Specification precisely mandates this behavior, which is more than an optimization, e.g. specifying that `"test"+""` still is a compile-time constant implies that you can use it as `case` label in a `switch` statement or in an annotation.

Answer (score 1):

From javadoc on `Field.set(..)`

```
 * <p>If the underlying field is final, the method throws an
 * {@code IllegalAccessException} unless {@code setAccessible(true)}
 * has succeeded for this {@code Field} object
 * and the field is non-static. Setting a final field in this way
 * is meaningful only during deserialization or reconstruction of
 * instances of classes with blank final fields, before they are
 * made available for access by other parts of a program. Use in
 * any other context may have unpredictable effects, including cases
 * in which other parts of a program continue to use the original
 * value of this field.
```

So you just use reflection in an incorrect way here.